# Mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$zview=$_POST['fio'];   
if(isset($_POST['view']))
{
    $prosmotr=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM techer WHERE name_teacher=''$zview''");
    $masv=mysql_fetch_array($prosmotr);

    echo $masv['disciplins1'];
    echo $masv['disciplins2'];
    echo $masv['disciplins3'];
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Вячеслав Ковалёв я с вас тащусь :)  А вопрос в чём?

Comment: У вас запрос не прошёл, и вернул `false`. Посмотрите, может таблица называется teacher? И что за две одинарных кавычки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: нашелся человек, который умеет читать мысли? )

Answer (score -1):

```
$prosmotr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM techer WHERE name_teacher='".$zview."'");
```

хотя я бы посоветовал бы там использовать LIKE:

```
name_teacher LIKE '".$zview."'"
```

и экранировать саму переменную $zview